OpenSSH for Windows SFTP logging is missing username after Windows Server 2022 October 2024 monthly update KB5044281
After Windows Server 2022 October 2024 monthly update KB5044281, the username is not logged for SFTP uploads or any other commands. Before the update it was listed in USER field. Now the username logged is only SYSTEM for all operations. All users are configured to operate in chroot jail.
We have hundreds of sftp integration accounts and at this point we cannot identify who is doing what. I checked KB5044281 file changes and all OpenSSH related files are in the list. So Microsoft has changed something regarding this.
Has anyone else noticed this change, or do you know how to get username shown in the event log for each operation?

17 days has gone. Is it just me in the whole world, who is interested about sftp logging? This issue is still not resolved. I've been trying to contact microsoft support, but no luck yet.
